# TToolButton (tbsDropDown) - down property not working correctly

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I have some issues with a TToolButton in Delphi XE4.

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  btn1.Style        := tbsDropDown;
  btn1.DropDownMenu := pmCreateReport1;
  btn1.PopupMenu    := pmCreateReport1;

  FDown     := True;
  btn1.down := FDown;
end;

procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDown     := not FDown;
  btn1.down := FDown;
end;
```

After FormCreate the down property is set to true and it works, but  when I click the button the down property is not working as expected. After the second click on the button the button should be down again.

The debugger says that the property is set to true, which is correct, but I cannot see it on the form.

When I am using a simple TToolButton without the style tbsdropdown its working as expected.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolButton.Down) explains it:

> Tool buttons can remain Down only if `Style` is `tbsCheck`.

You'll have to find some other way of achieving the representation you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ActionList`, set *AutoCheck* property **True**,

sample code:

```
const
  wm_tlbtnShowClosedClicked = WM_USER + 100;

TForm2 = class(TForm)
.....
private
procedure tlbtnShowClosedClicked(var Msg :TMessage); message wm_tlbtnShowClosedClicked;
end

procedure TForm2.tlbtnShowClosedClicked(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  btn1.Down := (btn1.Action as TAction).Checked;
end;
```